# Crystal Reports Goes Blank, Need IIS to Restart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I have published my web application in "windows server 2010". All my crystal reports are working fine.

Problem is: After Few hours all crystal reports shows blank page. When I restart my IIS, it starts working again.

Crystal Report.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ASPNetForms/SiteMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CrystalForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.ASPNetForms.CrystalForm" %>
```

CrystalForm.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strReportName = Session["ReportName"].ToString();
            var rptSource = Session["rptSource"];
            var xmlPath = Session["xmlPath"];

            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

            string strRptPath = Server.MapPath("~/") + "XML\\" + strReportName;
            rd.Load(strRptPath); //Loading Report
            rd.SetDataSource(rptSource);

            CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
            CrystalReportViewer1.HasCrystalLogo = false;
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exception = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to solve the issue closing and disposing report document in page unload.

```
protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rd.Close();
        rd.Dispose();
    }
```